# Create a valid rss date

Tags: bash, shell, date, scripting, rss

I want to convert a date like

```
Sat Dec 31 22:42:58 CET 2011
```

to a valid rss date which normaly looks like

```
Mon, 06 Sep 2009 16:45:00 +0000
```

Seconds should always be `00`. Is there anyway to do so? Besides it would be could to find out the current as a valid rss but that's optional ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

With your new sample input, you don't even need to reformat. It's as simple as

```
$ time="Sat Dec 31 22:42:58 CET 2011"; date -Rd "$time"
Sat, 31 Dec 2011 13:42:58 -0800
```

---

The trick is to reformat your date into a string that `date` can understand and take as input.  In this case it is `2011-12-31 13:37`.  I'm using `awk` to do this, but there are number of different utilities that will suffice.

```
#!/bin/bash

time="12-31-11 13:37"
date -Rd "$(awk -F'[- ]' '{printf("20%s-%s-%s %s\n", $3,$1,$2,$4)}' <<<"$time")"
```

#### Output

```
$ time="12-31-11 13:37"; date -Rd "$(awk -F'[- ]' '{printf("20%s-%s-%s %s\n", $3,$1,$2,$4)}' <<<"$time")"
Sat, 31 Dec 2011 13:37:00 -0800
```

Comment: didn't know about `date -d`, very nice

Comment: But could you tell me how I have to do this when I want to use it in a string? EDIT: I works in a string too :D

Comment: It's not exactly portable but it is immensely useful if your implementation supports it.

Comment: @MichealPerr as in your want to use the newly formated date in a string?

Comment: Except for the zero-seconds bit, this works for me: `date -R -d 'Sat Dec 31 22:42:58 CET 2011'`

Comment: @lhf thanks, that made it quite a bit shorter. Updated answer.

Comment: @MichealPerr See updated answer with the `-R` flag instead of explicitly defining the format. Also now with your new input format, it's much simpler